# How do I rig a spiral chord in Blender 2.93?

Tags: rigging

I'm working on an animated short involving a claw machine, and I'm trying to rig a spiral chord that connects a claw to the box it's dangling from. I can't seem to get it right. There aren't many tutorials on how to do this, but I've watched almost all of them and none of them are using version 2.93, which is what I'm using. I have everything modeled and I have a belzier curve for my chord, but that's all I have so far. I want to be able to animate the chord itself when the time comes, but I don't know what to do in order to make that happen.

Basically, I want the top of the chord to stay hooked to the cylindrical object near the top of the image. It needs to stretch when the claw drops and compress when the claw rises back up. It also needs to move dynamically according to the claw's movements. For example, if the claw hits something and turns at an angle, the chord should bend [like this](https://c.tenor.com/psBOxahhZqgAAAAM/cat-crawl-chroma.gif). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: hello, there are probably several ways, but what your cord is supposed to do?